# How to reload Springfox swagger configuration?

Tags: springfox

My application apart from static REST controllers used dynamic, which can be created through CRUD (one controller which find in DB required services and delegate execution to that service).
I'm creating dynamic ApiListing using plugins - one for creating ApiDescription and one for creating Definitions.

Is it possible to reload springfox configuration after some actions in application to load new versions of ApiDescription?